# Make Vim treat forward search as "up to and including"

Tags: vim

As a newcomer to Vim, I'm a big fan of the combination `c/[some_character]`. For example, I use `c/;` to change a line up to the final `;` in JavaScript.

However, I find it more intuitive to think of such a change us "change up to a certain character, *including that character*. This is particularly relevant given that something like `c$` changes all the way to the end of the line.

Is there a straightforward way to make this command behave as "up to and including" and to apply this to `d` and `y` as well?

I've thought about a custom keymap, but I can't figure out how to map a command that combines as `c` does.

Comment: for linewise use there is `f` (`cf;`). If you have to use the search, you can use `/;` and then `gnd` to delete until there, works also with `y` (`gny`) and everything else

Comment: `f` works perfectly. I didn't know about this command. Thanks!

Comment: then you should also know about `t` it is the same as `f` but without the searched char (faster than `/`). And `F` and `T` do the same backwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` is a motion that takes you to the *beginning* of the match. In combination with a change command, it does not include the first character. However, you can specify *search offsets*. To include the first matching character, you can append `/s+1` (start plus one character), or in case of a single character match, also `/e` (end of match). That, when combined with the `c`hange command, will include the character.

But I have a big surprise for you: This kind of search is so frequent, there's a special shortcut in vi and Vim: the `f{char}` command is the same as `/{char}/e<Enter>`! (And `t{char}` corresponds to `/{char<Enter>`.) Have a look at `:help f`; you'll also find uppercase variants that go in the opposite direction!

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Comment: Thanks! I use the built-in help a lot to look up commands, but the reverse is difficult: finding functionality and seeing what commands pertain to it. But I love Vim already even with limited knowledge.

Comment: Just keep browsing surrounding chapters and over time, you'll learn more and more. On a rainy weekend, you could read all of the user topics (`usr_01.txt` to `usr_45.txt`); that will provide you with a good coverage of all there is in Vim.

Comment: Maybe worth to mention, that `d/{char}/e` does not work, but `df{char}` does

Comment: I have also realised that `d/{multiple_chars}` works, but `f` takes a single char, so there's still a place for both.