# Vim - change up to and including searched string

Tags: vim, replace, full-text-search

Assuming I have the following code:

```
bool myCopiedFunc() {
    Some code that I've written;
    The cursor is on this line; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    if (something) {
        bool aValue;
        some of this is inside braces;
        return aValue;
    }
    if (somethingElse) {
        this is also inside braces;
        bool anotherValue;
        {
            more braces;
        }
        return anotherValue;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I decide I want to rewrite the remainder of the function, from the line with the cursor on it.

To replace up to a char on the same line, I can use `ct<char>` e.g. `ct;`
To replace up to and including a char on the same line I can use `cf<char>` e.g. `cf;`
To replace up to a string across multiple lines, I can use `c/<string>` e.g. `c/return false`
**To replace up to and including a string across multiple lines, I can use... ?? e.g. ??**

I can't just search for a semicolon, as there are an unknown number of them between the cursor and the end of the function, and counting them would be slow.
I can't just search for a closing brace, as there are several blocks between the cursor and the end of the function, and counting all closing braces would be slow.
With the help of code highlighting, I can easily see that the unique string I can search for is `return false`.

Is there an elegant solution to delete or change up to *and including* a string pattern?

I've already looked at a couple of related questions.

[Make Vim treat forward search as "up to and including"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223818/make-vim-treat-forward-search-as-up-to-and-including) has an accepted answer which doesn't answer my question.

In my case, I settled for deleting up to the search string, then separately deleting up to the semicolon, but it felt inefficient, and like it would have been quicker to just reach for the mouse. #firstworldproblems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To replace up to and including a string across multiple lines, I can
>   use... ?? e.g. ??

The `/` supports offsets.

In your case, you are gonna need the `e` offset, that is, `c/foo/e`.

You may want to know more details about "search offset":

```
:h offset
```

Comment: Spot on - I thought the 'e' would offset just the first word of the string (i.e. `return`). I'm using Vrapper in Eclipse, so :h doesn't work, but then I try actual vim, and it gives me page not found. I install the vim-doc package, still not found, but that's another problem altogether...

Comment: @M_M I have used eclipse for about 10 years till 2014. The vi-plugin, vrapper... they are not as good as ideavim in intellij.  even though the ideavim cannot compare to real vim, but it is ..at least... "usable". There is online vim doc too, you can do a google search. but standard vim installation should include the doc.

Comment: @M_M offsets are generally relative to the entire match, so /e means end of match

Comment: I tried this, and was pleased to see that `/e` matches the end of the whole string. Therefore, the bold line in my question should read: **To replace up to and including a string across multiple lines, I can use `c/<string>/e` e.g. `c/return false/e`**. This answer provided that information, so I have marked it as accepted, but I'm not sure whether to retrofit this line back into the question to make it more useful as an at-a-glance resource. The `foo` example doesn't demonstrate that `/e` handles more than one word without a number argument, unlike `e` in command mode.

Comment: @M_M thanx for accepting this answer. I don't understand your requirement. do you want to remove the `>>>>>cursor` line till the `return false;` line inclusively? why `/e` offset cannot work for you? do you mean you have multiple `return false;` statements in your file?

Comment: @Kent: Your answer is correct and the `/e` offset does work for me. The only question is whether to update the question to contain the answer in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll replace up to the closing brace associated to your current scope, you have `c]}`.

If you're looking for the end of the function, even if it means crossing to the upper scope, you'll need a plugin if the function may not be 0-indented as it's the case in C++, Java... See the related [Q/A on vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7942/626)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but up-voting for interpreting what I was trying to do. I had approached the problem by seeing a unique string and trying to replace up to and including it (but leaving the trailing semicolon to save typing; perhaps I was misguided in thinking I wouldn't type one anyway out of habit;;). The accepted answer provides an approach that is transferable to other situations, but you're correct that in this case I wanted to replace up to the end of the current scope. If I had thought of it that way, then your answer would have been exactly what I was looking for.